# Looking for step-by-step guide about "HTTP to HTTPS"

Tags: ssl, https

Question in the simplest way possible: I have a website which I want to make capable to use `https` - how to do it?

I heard about Google and its super powers, but the amount of results treating about ssl and https and so on, is too d* high. I'm really afraid to end up with incompatible certificates or empty bank account because of choosing wrong article or something out there.

I politely ask you to help me find the right articles about this topic. "Where do I start, where do I begin" as Chemical Brothers have sung.

- I have an account on shared hosting
- the very goal is to let users use my website through the https connections
- I have one domain
- all of images, javascript, css files are on the same domain

I'm aware of fact that maybe the best articles are right before my eyes (even now as I'm writing this question), but please - be understanding. I don't even know what should I know in the first place.

Thank you in advance for any guides.

Comment: This is server configuration, not programming. Once your server is set up properly to use SSL, then you just change ALL of your urls to use `https` instead of `http`. There should be almost NO other changes needed in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to create an SSL certificate. There are lots of sites out there that do it http://www.selfsignedcertificate.com/ or http://www.godaddy.com.

Once you have a certificate you need to install it on your web server. Depending on Windows or other OS you will do this differently.

Lastly you will configure you website to use https (port 443) rather than http (port 80). This is configured with IIS or Apache directly.

Hopefully [this](http://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation-microsoft-iis-7.htm) link for windows and [this](http://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation-apache.htm) for Apache helps a bit too.

If you are using another hosting application, just Google: install ssl certificate [myhostingApplication]

#### Update:

For shared hosting this will more than likely depend on your hosting provider. If you don't have access to IIS or similar, you more than likely will have to contact your provider directly. I use shared hosting with GoDaddy and they say:

> NOTE: If you want to install an SSL certificate on our shared hosting, Website Builder or Quick Shopping Cart®, you must purchase one of our SSL certificates. We do not install SSL certificates from other providers on our shared hosting accounts.

Your provider may be the same. So do be careful.

When I click on myAccount->SSL Certificates it redirects me to a page where I need to purchase one from GoDaddy. Upon purchasing one, I can then manage it from SSL Certificates on myAccount page.

Your provider may be different, since you haven't mentioned who they are,  you may just have to scour their knowledge base.

Comment: According to @Marc B comment under my question, your answer is valid if I have my own web server instead of account on shared hosting, right?

Comment: Not sure using `http://www.selfsignedcertificate.com/` is a good idea. Self-signed certificates already have their share of problems, but if someone else can also have their private keys (this service), that's clearly not ideal.

Comment: @Bruno the website does say not to use them in production, only use them in test/development environments. I put it there as it is a cheap option to purchasing full production, test and development certificates. It budget was tight, it is an easy way to go & you are willing to put up with the browser exception....